# How to regen PCG point cloud entity in AutoCAD2021

Tags: .net, autocad, autocad-plugin, objectarx

I have attached a PCG file with acdbAttachPointCloudEntity in AutoCAD2021. But every time when I zoom in and zoom out the point cloud is not getting regenerated, I need to regen it with REGEN command manually.

Is there any way to regen the PCG point cloud automatically while zoom and pan.